# Spring: password encryption

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

Here's my view:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Oswald|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/form.css}">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="register_main_wrapper">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <div id="register_form_wrapper">
                <div id="register_text_wrapper">
                    <h1 id="register_text">Создайте учётную запись</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="email_desc_reg_wrapper" class="desc_text">
                    <a>ЭЛЕКТРОННАЯ ПОЧТА</a>
                </div>
                <div id="email_input_reg_wrapper">
                    <input th:field="*{userEmail}"  type="email" size="35" class="input_fields">
                </div>
                <div id="nickname_desc_reg_wrapper" class="desc_text">
                    <a>ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ</a>
                </div>
                <div id="nickname_input_reg_wrapper">
                    <input th:field="*{userNick}" type="text" size="35" class="input_fields">
                </div>
                <div id="password_desc_reg_wrapper" class="desc_text">
                    <a>ПАРОЛЬ</a>
                </div>
                <div id="password_input_reg_wrapper">
                    <input th:field="*{userPass}" type="password" size="35" class="input_fields">
                </div>
                <div id="register_button_wrapper">
                    <button class="form_btn" id="register_button" type="submit" value="Submit">Регистрация</button>
                </div>
                <div id="login_switch_wrapper">
                    <a href="login" id="login_switch">Вход</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press submit, all attributes(pass,nick,email) goes to my controller, there is a part of it

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user)
{
    modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("register");
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerUser(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user)
    {

        User existingUser = userRepository.findByUserEmailIgnoreCase(user.getUserEmail());
        if(existingUser != null)
        {
            modelAndView.addObject("message","This email already exists!");
            modelAndView.setViewName("error");
        }
        else
        {
            userRepository.save(user);
```

I need to add password encryption to my app, so, as far as I know, I need to extract the password attribute from the model object, encrypt it and put it back. How can I extract attributes and return them to the model object?

Comment: `user.getPassword()` allows getting the password. `user.setPassword()` allows setting the password. Is that what you're asking? Note that password should not be encrypted. They should be salted then hashed using a strong, slow hashing algorithm (BCrypt or PBKDF2).

Comment: No you don't. See [tag:password-encryption] for why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the password from user , encrypt it with Spring encoder then set it again as a user password, your code will be like this :

```
//import the Spring encoder
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user) {

    // creating the instance class to use it
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    User existingUser =userRepository.findByUserEmailIgnoreCase(user.getUserEmail());
    if(existingUser != null)
    {
        modelAndView.addObject("message","This email already exists!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    }
    else
    {  //encrypt the password here
       String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
       user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
       userRepository.save(user);
```

You can find more in Spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) about PasswordEncoder Interface

Comment: The `PasswordEncoder`does not perform encryption. In every documented case from your link it performs secure hashing.